# How to Disable Remote validation in MVC3 for Specific View?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0

I am implementing remote validation in Registration and Login . my model property is

```
[RegularExpression(@"^[A-Za-z0-9._%+-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$", ErrorMessage = "* Invalid ")]
[Remote("ValidateUserId", "Registration")]
public String UserID { get; set; }
```

Controller:

```
 public JsonResult ValidateUserId(string UserID)
    {
        var Count = ObjDbRegistration.Tbl_Login.Where(c => c.UserID == UserID);


        if (Count.Count() > 0)
        {
            return Json("* User Already Exists", JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        return Json(true, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

this is validating Existing user at signup page at the same time Login page also . 
my requirement is not to validate in Login page.

Thanks

Comment: better you can use conditional validation of data annotation. check the [link](http://andrewtwest.com/2011/01/10/conditional-validation-with-data-annotations-in-asp-net-mvc/)

Comment: Simply you just need to remove the property from the ModelState